# Using a shader on part of the screen libGDX

Tags: libgdx, shader

I have used shaders to create simple black and white effects or blur effects across the entire screen. but is there a way to apply a shader to a portion of the screen. for example I would like to create an object in a game which is a piece of frosted glass that my character could walk behind. so I would Ideally create a shader to create a blur effect only on the area of the screen covered by the frosted glass. is this possible? or is there another approach more suitable?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just enable then disable the shader before and after you render the frosted glass.

For example using a `SpriteBatch`:

```
// Rendering code...

// First set the shader to be used
batch.setShader(myShaderProgram);

/*
Render your frosted glass here
*/

// Go back to the default shader (flushes the buffer too)
batch.setShader(null);

// More rendering code...
```